# How can I add sparkline from ng-apexcharts for Angular?

Tags: angular, apexcharts

`

```
<div>
  <div class="row">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div id="chart-1">
              <apx-chart
                [series]="chartLineSparkline1Options.series"
                [chart]="commonLineSparklineOptions.chart"
                [tooltip]="commonLineSparklineOptions.tooltip"
              ></apx-chart>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div id="chart-5">
              <apx-chart
                [series]="chartBarSparkline1Options.series"
                [chart]="commonBarSparklineOptions.chart"
                [plotOptions]="commonBarSparklineOptions.plotOptions"
                [tooltip]="commonBarSparklineOptions.tooltip"
              ></apx-chart>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import {
  ApexAxisChartSeries,
  ApexChart,
  ApexFill,
  ApexTooltip,
  ApexXAxis,
  ApexLegend,
  ApexDataLabels,
  ApexTitleSubtitle,
  ApexPlotOptions,
  ApexYAxis,
} from 'ng-apexcharts';

export type ChartOptions = {
  series: ApexAxisChartSeries;
  chart: ApexChart;
  xaxis: ApexXAxis;
  markers: any; //ApexMarkers;
  stroke: any; //ApexStroke;
  yaxis: ApexYAxis | ApexYAxis[];
  plotOptions: ApexPlotOptions;
  dataLabels: ApexDataLabels;
  colors: string[];
  labels: string[] | number[];
  title: ApexTitleSubtitle;
  subtitle: ApexTitleSubtitle;
  legend: ApexLegend;
  fill: ApexFill;
  tooltip: ApexTooltip;
};

declare global {
  interface Window {
    Apex: any;
  }
}

const sparkLineData = [
  47, 45, 54, 38, 56, 24, 65, 31, 37, 39, 62, 51, 35, 41, 35, 27, 93, 53, 61,
  27, 54, 43, 19, 46,
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  public chartAreaSparkline1Options: Partial<ChartOptions>;
  public chartAreaSparkline2Options: Partial<ChartOptions>;
  public chartAreaSparkline3Options: Partial<ChartOptions>;
  public chartLineSparkline1Options: Partial<ChartOptions>;
  public chartLineSparkline2Options: Partial<ChartOptions>;
  public chartLineSparkline3Options: Partial<ChartOptions>;
  public chartLineSparkline4Options: Partial<ChartOptions>;
  public chartBarSparkline1Options: Partial<ChartOptions>;
  public chartBarSparkline2Options: Partial<ChartOptions>;
  public chartBarSparkline3Options: Partial<ChartOptions>;
  public chartBarSparkline4Options: Partial<ChartOptions>;
  public commonAreaSparlineOptions: Partial<ChartOptions> = {
    chart: {
      type: 'area',
      height: 160,
      sparkline: {
        enabled: true,
      },
    },
    stroke: {
      curve: 'straight',
    },
    fill: {
      opacity: 0.3,
    },
    yaxis: {
      min: 0,
    },
  };
  public commonLineSparklineOptions: Partial<ChartOptions> = {
    chart: {
      type: 'line',
      width: 100,
      height: 35,
      sparkline: {
        enabled: true,
      },
    },
    tooltip: {
      fixed: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      x: {
        show: false,
      },
      y: {
        title: {
          formatter: function (seriesName) {
            return '';
          },
        },
      },
      marker: {
        show: false,
      },
    },
  };
  public commonBarSparklineOptions: Partial<ChartOptions> = {
    chart: {
      type: 'bar',
      width: 100,
      height: 35,
      sparkline: {
        enabled: true,
      },
    },
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        columnWidth: '80%',
      },
    },
    tooltip: {
      fixed: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      x: {
        show: false,
      },
      y: {
        title: {
          formatter: function (seriesName) {
            return '';
          },
        },
      },
      marker: {
        show: false,
      },
    },
  };

  constructor() {
    // setting global apex options which are applied on all charts on the page
    window.Apex = {
      stroke: {
        width: 3,
      },
      markers: {
        size: 0,
      },
      tooltip: {
        fixed: {
          enabled: true,
        },
      },
    };

    this.chartAreaSparkline1Options = {
      series: [
        {
          name: 'chart-big-sparkline',
          data: this.randomizeArray(sparkLineData),
        },
      ],
      colors: ['#DCE6EC'],
      title: {
        text: '$424,652',
        offsetX: 0,
        style: {
          fontSize: '24px',
        },
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: 'Sales',
        offsetX: 0,
        style: {
          fontSize: '14px',
        },
      },
    };

    this.chartAreaSparkline2Options = {
      series: [
        {
          name: 'chart-big-sparkline',
          data: this.randomizeArray(sparkLineData),
        },
      ],
      colors: ['#DCE6EC'],
      title: {
        text: '$235,312',
        offsetX: 0,
        style: {
          fontSize: '24px',
        },
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: 'Expenses',
        offsetX: 0,
        style: {
          fontSize: '14px',
        },
      },
    };

    this.chartAreaSparkline3Options = {
      series: [
        {
          name: 'chart-big-sparkline',
          data: this.randomizeArray(sparkLineData),
        },
      ],
      title: {
        text: '$135,965',
        offsetX: 0,
        style: {
          fontSize: '24px',
        },
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: 'Profits',
        offsetX: 0,
        style: {
          fontSize: '14px',
        },
      },
    };

    this.chartLineSparkline1Options = {
      series: [
        {
          name: 'chart-line-sparkline',
          data: this.randomizeArray(sparkLineData.slice(0, 10)),
        },
      ],
    };

    this.chartLineSparkline2Options = {
      series: [
        {
          name: 'chart-line-sparkline',
          data: this.randomizeArray(sparkLineData.slice(0, 10)),
        },
      ],
    };

    this.chartLineSparkline3Options = {
      series: [
        {
          name: 'chart-line-sparkline',
          data: this.randomizeArray(sparkLineData.slice(0, 10)),
        },
      ],
    };

    this.chartLineSparkline4Options = {
      series: [
        {
          name: 'chart-line-sparkline',
          data: this.randomizeArray(sparkLineData.slice(0, 10)),
        },
      ],
    };

    this.chartBarSparkline1Options = {
      series: [
        {
          name: 'chart-bar-sparkline',
          data: this.randomizeArray(sparkLineData.slice(0, 10)),
        },
      ],
    };

    this.chartBarSparkline2Options = {
      series: [
        {
          name: 'chart-bar-sparkline',
          data: this.randomizeArray(sparkLineData.slice(0, 10)),
        },
      ],
    };

    this.chartBarSparkline3Options = {
      series: [
        {
          name: 'chart-bar-sparkline',
          data: this.randomizeArray(sparkLineData.slice(0, 10)),
        },
      ],
    };

    this.chartBarSparkline4Options = {
      series: [
        {
          name: 'chart-bar-sparkline',
          data: this.randomizeArray(sparkLineData.slice(0, 10)),
        },
      ],
    };
  }

  public randomizeArray(arg): number[] {
    var array = arg.slice();
    var currentIndex = array.length,
      temporaryValue,
      randomIndex;

    while (0 !== currentIndex) {
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex -= 1;

      temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
      array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
      array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
  }
}
```

I want to add a sparkline in my angular project. I got these codes from apexcharts site, it works on the site, but when I import it to my own editor, the html codes give an error. In addition, the "arg" variable under the ts codes shows an error. Can you tell me the solution for this? Or if these codes do not exist, can you give another simple sparkline code?